# assigning to rvalue: why does this compile?

Tags: c++, reference, lvalue, rvalue

In the following example:

```
class A {
  private: double content;

  public:
  A():content(0) {}

  A operator+(const A& other) {     
    content += other.content;
    return *this;
  }

 void operator=(const A& other) {
       content = other.content;
  }

};
```

`A` is a simple wrapper for a double for which the `+` and `=` operators have been overloaded. In the following use:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a, b, c;
    (a+b) = c ; // Why is this operation legal?
}
```

**Why does `(a+b) = c` compile?** I would like to know why this statement is legal, because the result of `(a+b)` must be an `rvalue`. I am not returning a reference from `operator+`.

Comment: Overloaded operators are just function calls; they don't enjoy any special restrictions on the value categories of their arguments. Since you didn't ref-qualify the assignment operator overload, it accepts instances of any value category.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Well, you aren't complaining that `(a + b).display()` works, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(a+b) = c` is the same as `(a+b).operator=(c)`. There is no special rule for rvalue references in assignment operators, it just follows usual function call rules. If you want to prevent calling with rvalues, you can add a ref-qualifier:

```
void operator= (const A& other) & {
//                              ^
     content = other.content;
}
```

This will only allow the function to be called on lvalues.

Comment: so, normally = as the default assignment operator requires an lvalue on the left hand side ( apart from C++11 rvalue references), but when I overload = myself then that requirement goes out the window, right?

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII yes.

Comment: @TartanLlama No actually; the default `operator=` for a class type also allows a prvalue on the left-hand side. It doesn't make a difference whether there is a user-provided overload.   You're obviously referring to having a primitive type on the left (not sure if OP was also clear on that)