# What backward compatibility needs assignment for rvalues?

Tags: c++

*C++ Primer 5th*:

(Code are also from the book, 99% context provided here)

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //no error
    string s1 = "123", s2 = "aaaa";
    s1 + s2 = "wow";
    auto a = (s1 + s2).find("a");
}
```

> Prior to the new standard (here it's saying C++11), there was no way to prevent such usage. In
>   order to maintain **backward compatability**, the library classes continue
>   to allow assignment to rvalues, However, we might want to prevent such
>   usage in our own classes. In this case, we’d like to force the
>   left-hand operand (i.e., the object to which `this` points) to be an
>   lvalue.

What **backward compatibility** needs assignment for rvalues?

Btw, I am also curious about why `s1 + s2 = "wow"` is allowed but `int i = 3, j = 4; i + j = 7;` is not allowed. (Since it's closely related, I choose not to open another question)

Comment: I have no idea if the book is referring to some preceding code, but if you force `operator=` to be only called on l-values you might break preexisting code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33784173/1938163

Comment: Yes, the quoted text also says that providing a `&` can restrict a rvalue assignment. So some preexisting code used rvalue assignment? What's that for?

Comment: IMO this feels more like a quirk of implementing C++ manifesting itself as language rules.

Comment: @PasserBy: Indeed, rather like the `(int)` for postfix `++`.

Comment: In my opinion this is not a duplicate. The other question explains why this compile but I think the core of this question is why this was ever allowed or what kind of compatibility would have broken if this was restricted from c++11. The duplicated question doesn't answer "What backward compatability needs assignment for rvalues?"

Comment: I would assume if someone has this in their code that would not be a good thing. Even worse, if for some reason the rest of the codes breaks if it is removed that would be bad. I cannot imagine a reasonable answer, and would be interested in one.

Comment: Should I delete this question since now I think it does not have much practical benefits?

Answer (score 2):

This might be an anti-climatic educated guess. I will welcome any other concrete example, however following general rules seems very reasonable.

1. **Such limitation would not break any specific code but it would restrict domain of accepted programs. c++ is rather conservative when it comes to such changes**, sometimes to a great pain. A notable example would be most vexing parse, what code would break if `A a();` was interpreted as default-constructed `A`? Yet it doesn't work this way to be backwards-compatible with c syntax. That's a rather PIA for syntax analysis.
2. **c++ allows semantic redefinition of operator meaning for user defined types.** I don't know if there is a good example of semantic redefinition for `operator=` but **there are some rather notable examples for other operators.** [boost::program_options "abuses" `operator()` in a quite weird way, to create a concise syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp337681376), and [Eigen redefines comma operator semantics](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html). Pointer-to-member operators are often redefined to do something non-standard since they are not used by default often. So sometimes it's useful.
3. I guess it might be useful with classes where `operator=` has side effects, and is not necessarily meant to change the value in memory. I imagine that in some embedded development you can have `Row` and `Col` and you write `row * col = LED_ON` or something along the lines. Another example from top of my head is an expression library, for example, there is no `operator<=>` yet so `operator=` could be used in it's place to evaluate stuff like `(p ^ p) <=> p`.

`operator=` is no special among operators and those are not really much more special than other member functions. If you write a code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, A& a) { out << "A "; return out;}
};    

int main() {
    A a1, a2;
    cout << a1=a2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It will... break. That's because bitwise shift has [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) over `=`. It requires parentheses around `a1=a2`. This is to make a point that `operator=` really has no special rights in the language.

The other thing is that you can overload those operators nearly as you wish, so writing

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    bool operator=(A& rhs) {return true;}
};    

int main() {
    A a1, a2;
    cout << (a1=a2) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Is perfectly legal. Language provides operator with syntactic shortcuts and not much more. I don' think many complain that `(a+b).method()` works, this is the same for `(a+b).operator=()`.

**Bonus:** The example with `int`s doesn't work because you cannot overload operators for primitive types and the default one is defined so it doesn't accept rvalues. It exhibits the behaviour that you seem to expect. Basically we are stripped from the freedom of redefining semantics of primitive type operators.

Comment: The `boost::program_options` example is just a fluent interface, with the smallest (call site) method name possible. I wouldn't call that an "abuse"

Comment: I am not saying it's bad usage, though I would argue that overloading `operator()` was not meant to chain it. `instance.method()()()()` does look weird. Its possible to argue that any change to expected semantics is an abuse. Most are done in good faith and good result. I did put abuse into parentheses though, I didn't mean it in a bad way. More "like streams *abuse* bit shift operator".

Comment: "what code would break if A a(); was interpreted as default-constructed A?"  Every single C++ program in existence probably.

Comment: @n.m. Really so much codes do forward declare functions like that? Or is it used in standard library? Maybe I'm a newbie but don't think I've seen it yet.

Comment: How else do you want to declare a function that doesn't take arguments?

Comment: With a body... Especially within other scope, but making exception to parsing like this would be bad idea. Anyways, what do you think is more popular: default constructing objects or forward-declaring functions?

Comment: ...or using a keyword. I don't think there is any defending to most vexing parse working like it does, except for c compatibility.

Comment: So I gather you never write any headers?

Comment: I guess I am limited to classes and templates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of code that is currently perfectly valid (not even a warning with Clang) and that would break. The trick is that `operator +` returns a special object that has a redefined `operator =`.

In the example, the redefined `operator =` sets the first operand of the addition that created the special object:

```
#include <iostream>

// A simple class containing an int with a special operator =
class A {
public:
    int val;

    class B operator + (const A& other);
};

/* A very special subclass keeping a ref on the first member
 * of the addition of A objects that created it. This ref
 * will be assigned by operator = */
class B: public A {
    A& ref;      // ref on the A object used at creation time
    // private ctor: B can only be created from A objects sums
    B(A& orig): ref(orig) {
        this->val = orig.val;
    }

public:
    B(const B& src): A(src), ref(src.ref)  {}  // copy ctor...
    // second part of the trick: operator = assigns ref
    B& operator = (const A& src) {
        ref = src;
        return *this;
    }
    friend class A;
};

B A::operator +(const A& other) {
    B ret(*this);
    ret.val += other.val;
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    A a = {1}, b= {2}, c= {5};
    A d;

    d = a + b = c;
    // a+b will eval to a B having val=3 and ref=a
    // a+b = c will set a.val to 5 AFTER ABOVE EVALUATION
    // d = a+b will set d.val to 3

    std::cout << a.val << " " << b.val << " " << c.val << " " << d.val << std::endl;
    // outputs as expected: 5 2 5 3

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, I cannot imagine a real use case for that, but programmers can have strange ideas if the compiler accepts them (after all **I** could imagine that...). And I really think that letting `operator +` have side effects is an open door for operations like what I have shown.